# Wording for inheritance, heredity in programming

Tags: terminology, programming

I have objects which are related in two ways:

- Mother-child relation I called inheritance or heredity. It means that everything defined in the mother object gets inherited to the child.
- Language translation relation is similar, there is a object holding the english language, and objects with another language - which may contain a translation.
  That one I called i18n, for internationalization.

What I am looking for is how to name those properly? I believe inheritance is correct for the mother-child. But the i18n - well it does not imply a relation as such. At first I was going to call it inheriti18n .. but I don't like it.

I hope there exist be some meangingfull terms for this, that my synonym search did not find.

---

I have a Product parent, the product has childs - its subproducts.
Each product- being parent or child, can have translations. Those translations from the parent can be passed down to childs.

Comment: inheriti18n makes no sense. i18n is tech jargon, since internationalisation has 18 letters in between the i and the n. That doesn't hold for inheriti18n

Comment: Yes thought that too, but making it like ..
inheritinternationalistation
i24n .. is not meanginfull either nor intuitive. So I am really looking for something else.
Maybe I should just use, inherit-language, inherit-data ?

Comment: The version in English is the **original**, **progenitor**, or **source** of the translated versions. (The resulting versions are simply **translations**.) But I can't turn any of that into an answer, because you haven't given enough to determine which would be a better fit. Making up *inherit18n* would (I think) certainly be the wrong approach.

Comment: In programming we usually talk about parent-child relationships, not mother-child, with child objects inheriting from a parent object (or chain of parent objects).

Comment: Hm I struggle giving a good example or more details, tried making a short example.
I think now, the parent->child relation is inheritance, but source->translation - not sure - my brain tells me "internationalization" yet it feels wrong.

Comment: The "internationalization" relationship is a bit like a parameterized type, or a C++ template. You might want to look at some of the software engineering and programming Stack Exchange sites.